# thunderbird's "quick filter" has stopped working on Horus

Tags: gala, thunderbird

Thunderbird's all-important "Quick Filter" tab has stopped working under recent updates to Horus (i.e. it used to work just fine under Horus). More specifically, clicking on the "Quick Filter" tab just causes it to turn grey, but the search bar does not appear underneath it, and so it cannot be used.

Although Thunderbird is an unsupported app, this sudden loss of functionality is almost certainly due to one of the many recent improvements to Elementary's "gala" window manager. It is therefore likely that it affects other programs as well.

I've tried both the flatpak and apt repository versions (both of which are 102.10.0), and it makes no difference. So I hope someone at Elementary will look into it (it's probably just a refresh problem of some kind, perhaps in Thunderbird's css style sheet, but that's beyond my paygrade).

Answer (score 0):

I have now found that when thunderbird is started in "Troubleshoot" mode, the "Quick Filters" search bar does appear as it should, BUT nothing happens when text is typed into it, so it's still useless (curiously, the "Unread", "Starred" etc. filter buttons do work, however).

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem but it may help you. There is a Thunderbird fork actively developed and maintained called Betterbird. You should try it (https://www.betterbird.eu/)

Comment: You're right: I have exactly the same problem with betterbird! Which just reinforces my belief that the folks at Elementary have tweaked gala in some way that's not good for everyone ...